# How do I implement image elements of unequal width in simplyScroll?

Tags: jquery, css, image, width, listitem

I'm using [simplyScroll v1](http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/horizontal.html) to horizontally scroll images of varying width but the list items containing the images are of a fixed width.

You can view the scrolling content [here](http://www.creenanstud.com/).

**How do I achieve list items with varying width?**

The author suggests the following:

> If you do want to scroll unequal size
>   elements try putting them in a
>   container div, then initialising
>   simplyScroll on that (note that this
>   hack will essentially double the
>   amount of elements scrolled!)

The list already appears to be within a container div:

```
div.simply-scroll-container
```

What does the author mean by "initializing" on the container div?

A similar thread exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489737/jquery-slider-with-variable-width-elements) though it is ambiguous to me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the li is set in the simply-scroll css file, so if you wish to use varying sizes you can simply remove the width property:

Before: 
`.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
            float: left;
            /*width: 290px;*/ width: 290px;
            /*height: 200px;*/ height: 180px;
        }`

After: 
`.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li {
            float: left;
            /*height: 200px;*/ height: 180px;
        }`

Comment: No luck Steve. None of the images display in Chrome. In FireFox, one of the images vertically stacks beneath the first image. If it were as simple as this, I believe the author wouldn't have provided the "hack" I quoted in my question. I can't figure out why but the scrolling seems contingent on list item width in some way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem that version 2 (coming out very soon!) fixes by automatically wrapping the element you are trying to scroll. For now do it manually.

If you had this list of unequal width/height elements

`<ul id="scroller">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    etc...
</ul>`

wrap it in another div so you just scroll one.

`<div id="scroller"><ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    etc...
</ul>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by combining both of the answers already provided;

- Wrap the `<ul>` into its own `<div id="scroller">`
- Remove the fixed `width` property from the `.simply-scroll .simply-scroll-list li` element in the CSS
- Add `padding` to this element as required.

Working in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps for you. Its over 2 years since question were written.

It is solution for different widths of each image inside li

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('#scroller li img').each(function(){
      var widthThis = $(this).width();

      $(this).parent().css({
        width : widthThis
      })
   });
$("#scroller").simplyScroll({
    pauseOnHover: false
});
```

});